# \varprojlím and \varinjlím

Tags: symbols

I am typing some texts in Spanish, and I need to use the symbols for inverse and direct limits—`\varprojlim` and `\varinjlim` respectively. The problem is that these symbols look like "lim" with an arrow below, but I need "l**í**m" with an accent over i. Is there an easy way to define something like that?

I think I found the definitions [in the amsmath sources](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsopn.dtx):

```
\def\varinjlim{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\rightarrowfill@\textstyle}}\nmlimits@
}
\def\varprojlim{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\varlim@{\leftarrowfill@\textstyle}}\nmlimits@
}
```

But I am not sure how to modify this properly.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve it with a simple patch, which probably should be the default also for `amsmath`: Since `babel-spanish` already solves the problem for `\lim`, we can just use the command instead of the explicit `lim` in the definition of `\varlim@`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\varlim@}{lim}{\lim}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\lim\varinjlim\varprojlim$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output after adding `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`:

[image]

For “colimit”:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\colim}{co{\lim}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\varlim@}{lim}{\lim}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$\lim\colim\varinjlim\varprojlim$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that really solves the problem, and I even don't have any issues with my exotic font (`\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`). Do you know how "lím" with an accent is defined properly? I want to copy that definition to have "colím".

Comment: @DonAlejo “I'm Mr. egreg, I solve problems”, see edit.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a perfect solution and I am going to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-define `\varlim@`:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools}

\makeatletter\def\varlim@#1#2{%
\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
\hfil$#1\operator@font l\'{i}m$\hfil\cr
\noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}#2\cr
\noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \varinjlim( E_{α},f_{α\,β}),\quad\varprojlim( E_{α},f_{β\,α}),\]%

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's probably a different question, but I use another font: I have `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` in the preamble. This makes the accented letters disappear in math mode. How do I fix it? I tried `\acute{\i}`, but the dotless i is not displayed correctly. Something like `\text{\rm l\'im}` works, but it seems wrong (?)

Comment: Probably `\operatorname{l\'im}` is more correct.

Comment: The accented letter disappears (but it's some issue with the font, I guess).

Comment: I'm not sure that four messages `Command \' invalid in math mode` per use of one of the commands is acceptable.

Comment: @egreg: I thought `\operatorname` made its argument typeset in textmode. I didn't have time to test it.