# Changing the definition of "\mod" in spanish impossible?

Tags: spanish

I'm writing a math text in spanish and want to change the definition of the "\mod" command. However, this seems impossible, as the following MWE shows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\mod}{\operatorname{changed}}

\begin{document}
$a \equiv b \mod c$
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

However, if I comment the line

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

in the above code, the result I get is

[image]

as I would expect.

The same phenomenon happens with other math operators that carry accents in spanish, like for example "\max" or "\lim", but it works for such that don't have accents, like "\sin".

Comment: Move the redefinition behind begin document

Comment: Is your aim to avoid the accent in the operator names?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, your suggestion precisely solves my problem. If you post it as an answer y can accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that your aim is to use the standard *unaccented* operator names.

The trick is explained it the manual for [`babel-spanish`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.pdf), section 5.5.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% no accents in math operators
\unaccentedoperators

\begin{document}

$a \equiv b \mod{c}$

$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$

$\arcsin t$

$\max A-\min A$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware that `\mod` is not defined with `\operatorname` and your proposed redefinition would be bad anyway.

Anyway, here's a correct way to proceed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\unaccentedoperators

\makeatletter
\addto\mathspanish{\renewcommand{\mod}{\operatorname{m\es@op@ac od}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \equiv b \mod c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the accent irrespective of `\accentedoperators` or `\unaccentedoperators`, remove the `\es@op@ac` command.

In general, I don't recommend redefining some standard command to do different things (apart from printing just a different symbol). Better defining `\omod` or whatever name you prefer.

Comment: +1: Is \unaccentedoperators part of babel then?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, see babel-manual.pdf section 27 (which is about the Spanish language options).

Comment: Actually I do want to use the accented versions because they seem to be quite standard in spanish math texts, and I do want \mod to behave like an operator (as this fits my mathematical needs better). For the same reason I want to redefine \lim to denote categorical limits instead of analytic ones, so in any case this wouldn't solve my issue.

Comment: @MichaelFütterer I added a different version. I'm not sure where categorical limit notation is different from analytic notation.

Comment: Thanks, with that I'll be able to solve the problem! For the categorical limit I just realized that a solution is already described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342037/varprojl%c3%adm-and-varinjl%c3%adm