# how to create an operator like varinjlim

Tags: amsmath

I want to create an operator with an arrow beneath, like `\varinjlim`. Writing `$\mathop{\mathsf{elts}}\limits_{\longrightarrow}(F)$` gives me roughly what I want, but there is a bigger space over the arrow, and the arrow head is smaller than in `\varinjlim`. See below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
$\mathop{\mathsf{elts}}\limits_{\longrightarrow}(F)$ $\varinjlim(D)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the same spacing and arrow size as `$\varinjlim$`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Creating a variant of `\varinjlim` without redefining `\varinjlim` itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630294/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630298/125871) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342041/125871):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\injelts}{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\inj@lts{{\mathsf{elts}}{\rightarrowfill@\textstyle}}}\nmlimits@
}
\def\inj@lts#1#2{\inj@@lts#1#2}
\def\inj@@lts#1#2#3{%
  \vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\cr
    \hfil$#1#2$\hfil\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1.5\ex@}#3\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-\ex@}\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
$\varinjlim(F)\injelts(F)$
\end{document}
```